# MySQL тишина после mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, linux, debian, lighttpd

Я новичек, использую PHP второй день. Сегодня совершенно внезапно перестала работать функция `mysql_connect()`. Например, код который я вызываю:

```
echo "some string1...";
$bd_link = @mysql_connect( $this->mysql_addr, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass );
echo "some string2...";
```

`echo "some string1..."` проходит, `echo "some string2..."` уже не выполняется, и вообще в браузере тишь да гладь, ни ошибок, ничего (а вывод ошибок включен). Странно что вчера все работало. И mysql, и нужная база стоят на месте.

Что же это может быть?

Веб-сервер lighttpd, mysql 5.5.46, php 5.6.14

**Решено. Проблема была в неустановленом пакете php5-mysql**

Comment: Не знал что `@` для подавления ошибок, думал это для того чтобы получить ссылку на объект вместо самого объекта. Убрал, теперь вижу ругань `Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`. Буду гуглить, почему.

Comment: Не гуглите, смотри доку – http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php, эта функция устарела и у вас ее уже нет

Comment: Как она так быстро исчезла? Вчера только все работало, и я не делал никаких обновлений.

Comment: Этого я не знаю и не хочу гадать, я смотрю на факты – ошибка говорит за себя. Смотрите мой ответ, лучше использовать другой драйвер для работы с БД

Comment: Проблема решилась доустановкой `php5-mysql`, видимо я все-таки его удалил, хотя не пойму когда и как я это сделал. Извините ребята, теперь все работает. Обязательно посмотрю в сторону `mysqli`. Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам помог ответ, отметьте его как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Всегда смотрите логи! У вас наверняка фатальная ошибка.

2) Не используйте подавление ошибок через `@`, потом такой код невозможно будет отладить.

3) `mysql_connect` устарело с 5.5, используйте [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) или [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php)

4) Всегда смотрите документацию – http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

Если вы новичок, то сразу начинайте использовать PDO или mysqli.

Функция mysql_connect() является устаревшей и не рекомендуется к использованию:

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php